# Deploy infragistics on appharbor

Tags: asp.net, infragistics, appharbor

Has anyone successfully deployed a website with infragistics controls on appharbor using the "lib" folder option?
If yes, can you please post step by step info?

Comment: I haven't tried this, though I did see another issue in the past where someone had issues with the license compiler locating the license assembly when deploying to appharbor.  If that is what you are getting, you could try removing the references to the NetAdvantage controls from the licenses.licx file before deploying.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have appharbor-specific details, but when we deploy ig we make sure the references are  "Copy Local" true.

We also reference our scripts via web.config like this

```
<configSections>
  <section name="infragistics.web" type="System.Configuration.SingleTagSectionHandler,System, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
</configSections>

<infragistics.web imageDirectory="/ig_common/Images/" javaScriptDirectory="/ig_common/20102/scripts/" enableAppStyling="false" />
```

If you're trying to get appharbor to build your solution on the server this isn't going to work: http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/ed_blankenship/archive/2007/07/16/building-apps-using-netadvantage-with-team-build.aspx